# Detecting drag drop to HTML textbox?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a normal search box on my webpage. It is filled with text: `Search this website`

This text is removed when you click into the box to type your search query:

```
onfocus="if(this.value=='Search this website') { this.value=''};
```

But how can I detect when someone drags text from the page onto the search box, as I often do myself? `onfocus` is not triggered and the previous text remains.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the *ondrop* event, which will only fire if the *ondragenter* and *ondragover* events are cancelled.  Turns out it's a bit trickier than that because the behavior is different in Firefox than IE, Safari and Chrome.

```
(function () {
    var inp = document.getElementById("test"),
        chg = false;

    inp.ondragover = inp.ondragenter = function () {
        chg = inp.value == "Drop here";
        return false;
    }
    inp.ondrop = function (evt) {
        evt = evt || event;

        if (chg) {
            this.value = evt.dataTransfer.getData("text")
                         || evt.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain");
            return false;
        }
    }
})();
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/23vB6/) - Firefox 3+, IE5+, Chrome and Safari.  Near as I can tell, Opera doesn't support the event.  At least you can get it working for 95% of your visitors though.

[Drag Operations - MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DragDrop/Drag_Operations)

Comment: @Tim: IE, Firefox, Chrome and Safari (complete with working example).  Was a bit of a pain getting it to work in Firefox because it changes the value of the input before firing the drop event.  The solution was to move the value check to the *ondragover/ondragenter* event.  Opera is the odd one out, these events are unsupported there, but there's no harm in using them for the browsers that do support them.

Comment: Cool. I did seem to remember it being a bit tricky last time I looked at this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the `onchange` event?

BTW, there is a nifty little [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) plugin called [jquery-defaultvalue](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-defaultvalue/) which handles all the corner cases for you. If you're using jQuery anyway, it's worth a look.

Comment: I checked, and *jquery-defaultvalue* actually only handles the focus and blur events.  It doesn't look like it handles any corner cases at all :-)

Answer (score 0):

See - http://www.simplecoding.org/drag-drop-s-ispolzovaniem-html5.html , but page on the russian language (Google Translate would help).