# How to listen for drag and drop plain text in textarea with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, textarea

I want a user to be able to drag and drop plain text (external to the browser) into a textarea, and listen for this event.

In chrome at least, `.change()` does not pick up on this, and jQueryUI `.droppable()` only seems to work with html elements, not plain text. Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This seems to work fine in IE7+, FF6, and Chrome (does not work on Safari):

```
$("textarea")
    .bind("dragover", false)
    .bind("dragenter", false)
    .bind("drop", function(e) {
        this.value = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData("text") ||
            e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain");

        $("span").append("dropped!");

    return false;
});
```

*(Basically adapted from [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554646/detecting-drag-drop-to-html-textbox))*

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/2cJZY/
Looks like you must cancel the `dragover` (and `dragenter`) event to catch the `drop` event in Chrome.

Comment: This works, however, the text being dragged is no longer placed into the textarea

Comment: @dave: Ach; I should have paid more attention, sorry about that.

Comment: No problem, do you have any idea as to how to capture whatever is being dragged arbitrarily?

Comment: @dave: I have a few ideas, I'm going to play around with this to get it working on Chrome and I'll update the answer.

Comment: Awesome! In the meantime, I am just using setInterval to check the input every 100 ms, but I feel like that is kind of bad practice.I had no idea that this was such a subtle issue when I started.

Comment: @dave: Yeah turns out the whole D&D thing is kind of a mess across browsers. I'm interested in finding out a cross-browser solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

How about checking another event like onfocus?

Store the value of the textarea, onfocus of the text area, check if a change was made.

Comment: onFocus does not trigger either