# Why doesn't `.draggable()` have a `dropped` event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I would like to fire an event when a specific draggable element is dropped in any droppable element.

Each droppable element has a `drop` event, but using that would be awkward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it would be nonsense. Droppable has `drop`, Draggable has `drag`, why should object with Draggable interface has event `dropped` which is from its name `event for droppable when it's released`

You can implement bind (`dragover`,`dragenter`,`drop`) to object which should receive dropped element, but this shouldn't be default for Draggable [(info)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237436/how-to-listen-for-drag-and-drop-plain-text-in-textarea-with-jquery)

Or try to create what you need via `dragstop` callback in Draggable